# Define parameters in JSDoc for inline anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, annotations, phpstorm, jsdoc

If I define the function as a variable object, then PhpStorm will show the auto-complete for the `item` parameter.

```
        /**
         * @param {Rules.FolderGroupItem} item
         **/
        var forEach = function(item) {
            if(item.type == 'label')
            {
                str += this.renderLabel(item.paramType);
            }
            if(item.type == 'input')
            {
                str += this.renderInput(item.paramType);
            }
        };
        _.each(items,forEach,this);
```

If I write the same thing as an inline parameter for the `_.each()` function. Then it doesn't work.

```
        _.each(items,forEach,
            /**
             * @param {Rules.FolderGroupItem} item
             **/
            function(item) 
        {
            if(item.type == 'label')
            {
                str += this.renderLabel(item.paramType);
            }
            if(item.type == 'input')
            {
                str += this.renderInput(item.paramType);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer. Here it is.

```
    _.each(items,forEach,function(/*Rules.FolderGroupItem*/item) 
    {
        if(item.type == 'label')
        {
            str += this.renderLabel(item.paramType);
        }
        if(item.type == 'input')
        {
            str += this.renderInput(item.paramType);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where in the docs did you find this? My editor doesn't seem to understand it

Comment: @PVarga: I'm a bit late to the show, but see my answer. (Use a starting double ** when writing the comment for the parameter.)

Answer (score 2):

I had to write a **double** `**` at the beginning of the comment for me to work.
Using PhpStorm 2022.3.2, Build #PS-223.8617.59.
Thank you [@Reactgular](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1031569/reactgular) for the hint.

```
/**
 *
 * @type {Array<Assignment>}
 */
let arr = [];
_.each(arr, /**Assignment*/ itemInArray => {

});
```

This way code completition is also working fine:
[image]